# How to read a text from dynamic added TextBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have one question about how to read a text from dynamically added TextBox. In my UserForm I have one TextBox and in this TextBox I put a number of how much new TextBoxes I want add. From this one TextBox I add two new dynamic TextBox.

```
Set Ctrl = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", Window.Name + CStr(i)) 'TextBox for code
With Ctrl
    .Width = 32
    .Height = 16
    .Top = TopPos
    .Left = 6
    .Value = Chr(64 + i) + CStr(10 + i)
    .MaxLength = 4
    .ZOrder (0)
End With
Set Ctrl = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", Window.Name + CStr(i)) 'TextBox for comment
With Ctrl
    .Width = 240
    .Height = 16
    .Top = TopPos
    .Left = 44
    .MaxLength = 50
    .ZOrder (0)
End With
```

First column of TextBoxes is filling automatically with a letter and a number,  a second column is empty for my comments. With Finish button I want to export text from  both TextBoxes to a two cells - text from first column of TextBoxes to a cell "A" and text from second column of TextBoxes to a cell "B" in new file.
I wrote a function to find a text in each of new TextBoxes:

```
Function FindName(Iter As Integer, Name As String) As String
   Dim Text As String
   Dim Ctrl As Control

   For Each Ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
   If Ctrl.Name = Name Then
      Text = Ctrl.Text
   End If
   Next Ctrl

FindName = Text

End Function
```

I use this function to fill up a new Excel with text from TextBoxes, but the problem is, that a text is exported only from the second column to a new file:

```
NewFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(StartValue + i, 1) = FindName(i, "TextBox1" + CStr(i))
NewFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(StartValue + i, 2) = FindName(i, "TextBox1" + CStr(i))
```

Is there any solution how to distinguish the text from first column of TextBoxes and from second column of TextBoxes to export a text from first TextBox to one cell and from second TextBox to another cell?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: In your two function calls, you are using the same textbox name. Btw the concatenator should be & rather than +.

Comment: What is `Window.Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you retrieve the controls by name, you need to give them unique name. This is done with the second parameter of the `.Add`-command. In your code, you give the controls for code and comment the same name and therefore the `FindName`-function can find only one of them. Have a look to the following code - it creates TextBoxes with names like `tbCode_1` and `tbComment_1` - change it to your personal taste if you don't like it.

```
Set Ctrl = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "tbCode_" &  CStr(i)) 'TextBox for code
(...)
Set Ctrl = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "tbComment_" &  CStr(i)) 'TextBox for comment
```

Your `FindName`-function could look like

```
Function FindName(Iter As Integer, colName As String) As String
    Dim ctrlName as String
    ctrlName = "tb" & colName & "_" & CStr(i)
    On Error Resume Next
    FindName = Me.Controls(ctrlName).Text
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

and you call it with

```
NewFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(StartValue + i, 1) = FindName(i, "Code")
NewFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(StartValue + i, 2) = FindName(i, "Comment")
```

Comment: It works, thank you for the help. Window.Name was a name of TextBox that I put a number of new dynamic TextBoxes and I forgot to replace a "Window.Name" with the name for a new TextBox.